# Rsync - not transferring empty files

Tags: linux, shell, command, rsync

I want to use `rsync` to transfer files from server to my own pc, but there's some empty files in the server side. I doesn't need those files, what is the command of `rsync` in this situation(transfering all files except for the empty ones)?

Comment: Why not remove the empty files after transfer? `find someDir/ -size 0b -exec rm -f {} \;`

Comment: There are many times that empty files serve an important purpose, sometimes as a flag, other times to help with permissions.  Further, it takes (almost) no time to transfer them.  So, rather than inadvertently breaking something, users generally want `rsync` to transfer these files.  If you aren't one of those users,  @ElliottFrisch's solution is a good one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use min-size option of rsync command

```
 --min-size=SIZE         don't transfer any file smaller than SIZE
```

So `--min-size=1` will skip empty files